# Error during migration of /home to a separate partition - not able to log in anymore

Tags: home-directory, restore

I was trying to move my home directory to a partition on my hard drive, as shown by this tutorial:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving 
I can only log into the guest account, so sudo is out of the question.
these are the commands I ran:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
cmp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

and added these lines into it(at bottom)

```
# (identifier)  (location, eg sda5)   (format, eg ext3 or ext4)      (some settings) 
UUID=????????   /media/home    ext3          defaults       0       2
```

then I ran

```
sudo mkdir /media/home
sudo mount -a
sudo rsync -aXS --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/. /media/home/.
```

I then tryed to do this:

```
cd / && sudo mv /home /old_home && sudo mkdir /home
```

but got an error:`mv: /home currently in use` or something like that so I rebooted and it said something was very wrong with my home directory.

When I try to log in, I cant.  I get a black screen and then back to login.
I can boot into Windows and edit files manually if that helps.

Comment: Did you add the two lines to fstab just as you posted them or did you replace the ??? (and maybe the ext3), as you must do it according to the tutorial?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to `mv /home` of the running system that you are logged into - did you maybe miss the *"First, you'll need to shut down, and reboot from a LiveCD or USB stick"* step of the instructions?